# What could cause a peak to split into 2 resonances as temperature increases in NMR spectroscopy

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy, temperature

I understand that some peaks may coalesce upon an increase in temperature due to an increase in free rotation, this does occur with some peaks in my data. Why might you see a peak split into two other peaks? I have thought it may be to do with an equilibrium shift in a rapid conversion between species but really I would expect that to show as one peak shrinking and another one growing. The observed effect is one peak clearly splitting into two. Any ideas why this could happen?

Edit:
The sample is a diamagnetic complex with aromatic ligands with t-Bu groups in the meta and para positions. It is hard to assign peaks as I believe there may be an equilibrium between different conformations in solution. The peak that splits is in the alkyl region of the NMR (around 1.5 ppm) and probably corresponds to some part of the t-Bu groups. The 2 peaks produced do appear to get sharper with temperature and the two peaks are the same size, however the difference in chemical shift (between the 2 peaks) at higher temperature is much greater than the linewidth at the lower temperature (where it is one peak), so I'm not sure if this could be J-coupling being resolved.

If it was the case of 2 conformers being present, would you not expect the single peak to reduce in intensity as another separate peak appears and increases in temperature? Rather than a splitting into 2 new peaks?

[image]

Comment: Is the  peak (are the peaks) getting sharper as you increase T? Are the peaks symmetrical (same intensity)? You might be narrowing the lines, allowing you to resolve a J coupling.

Comment: May you add an example where you *observe* such splitting of one into two / multiple peaks while increasing the sample temperature?

Comment: What kind of sample are you measuring?

Comment: As others saud give an example.  Nevertheless, by intuition the T might be enough to access two conformers rather than provide free rotation and equalize the splitting. It seems reasonable.

Comment: That's pretty cool looking data. I don't know that this question needed to be put on hold. It helps that you provided the data. Would be nice with some additional info regarding T and particularly field strength (scale is ppm but what is it in Hz) etc, but it's quite clear my hunch was right, except that the coupling would be little big :), so actually prob not a J splitting.

Comment: I have a stupid question. Are you sure the higher temperature is top of that series?

Comment: I'd quite like to see the structure. This would really help eliminate some of the possibilities.

Comment: Sorry for not including too much, obviously this is unpublished so I wouldn't want to upset anyone in my research group by sharing too much! The top is definitely the higher temperature, even if it weren't there are two other examples of coalescence going in the expected direction so if if you reversed the temperature it would be even more surprising! Thanks for all the thoughts everyone, you've given me a lot to think about.

Answer (score 6):

Since I do not know which compound it is, my guess is that you have two different  $\ce{H^1}$ that have almost the same chemical shift at room temperature. The chemical shifts change with temperature as for instance in sucrose:

[image]

Here  are represented mainly the  $\ce{H^1}$  of the $\ce{-OH}$ but the $\ce{C-H}$ (the peak of **1**) shifts also.

In your case,  one is almost fixed, while the other one moves to higher $\delta$  and, therefore, they split into two.

More info on the sucrose spectrum [here](http://u-of-o-nmr-facility.blogspot.com/2014/03/variable-temperature-to-improve-nmr.html?m=1).